# Update 1 column based on changing values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reportbuilder3.0

I have  a table with sample data below:

```
ID    | RecordID  | Time     | Start/End
1       1111       09:00:10          
5       1111       09:00:12    
13      1111       09:01:10   
24      1111       09:02:30          
27      9999       10:00:10          
29      9999       10:01:22   
30      9999       10:03:10          
38      7777       10:20:10          
59      7777       10:21:10   
60      7777       10:24:10          
71      1111       14:20:10          
72      1111       14:21:10   
75      1111       14:24:10
```

How do I query the table to add a 1 to the `Start/End` column when the RecordID is the first and last instance?

```
ID    | RecordID  | Time     | Start/End
1       1111       09:00:10          1
5       1111       09:00:12    
13      1111       09:01:10   
24      1111       09:02:30          1
27      9999       10:00:10          1
29      9999       10:01:22   
30      9999       10:03:10          1
38      7777       10:20:10          1
59      7777       10:21:10   
60      7777       10:24:10          1
71      1111       14:20:10          1
72      1111       14:21:10   
75     1111       14:24:10          1
```

Do I need to loop through the table?

Please note that the RecordID can be in the table more than once throughout the day.

```
EDIT -----------------------------
```

Aplogies, i originally stated the ID would be incremental but that is not the case - the above table is what it would look like if i pulled out the data for 1 user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bce28/1)**

```
UPDATE t
SET [Start/End] = CASE WHEN t1.ID is null or t2.ID is null
     THEN 1
     WHEN t.RecordID <> t1.RecordID OR t.RecordID <> t2.RecordID
     THEN 1 END 
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
  ON t1.ID = t.ID - 1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
  ON t2.ID = t.ID + 1
```

Result:

```
| ID | RECORDID |     TIME | START/END |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|
|  1 |     1111 | 09:00:10 |         1 |
|  2 |     1111 | 09:00:12 |    (null) |
|  3 |     1111 | 09:01:10 |    (null) |
|  4 |     1111 | 09:02:30 |         1 |
|  5 |     9999 | 10:00:10 |         1 |
|  6 |     9999 | 10:01:22 |    (null) |
|  7 |     9999 | 10:03:10 |         1 |
|  8 |     7777 | 10:20:10 |         1 |
|  9 |     7777 | 10:21:10 |    (null) |
| 10 |     7777 | 10:24:10 |         1 |
| 11 |     1111 | 14:20:10 |         1 |
| 12 |     1111 | 14:21:10 |    (null) |
| 13 |     1111 | 14:24:10 |         1 |
```

**EDIT**

New Query:
**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41dd/1)**

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) rnka
FROM Table1)


UPDATE t
SET [Start/End] = CASE WHEN t1.ID is null or t2.ID is null
     THEN 1
     WHEN t.RecordID <> t1.RecordID OR t.RecordID <> t2.RecordID
     THEN 1 END 
FROM CTE t
LEFT JOIN CTE t1
  ON t1.rnka = t.rnka - 1
LEFT JOIN CTE t2
  ON t2.rnka = t.rnka + 1
```

Result:

```
| ID | RECORDID |     TIME | START/END |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|
|  1 |     1111 | 09:00:10 |         1 |
|  5 |     1111 | 09:00:12 |    (null) |
| 13 |     1111 | 09:01:10 |    (null) |
| 24 |     1111 | 09:02:30 |         1 |
| 27 |     9999 | 10:00:10 |         1 |
| 29 |     9999 | 10:01:22 |    (null) |
| 30 |     9999 | 10:03:10 |         1 |
| 38 |     7777 | 10:20:10 |         1 |
| 59 |     7777 | 10:21:10 |    (null) |
| 60 |     7777 | 10:24:10 |         1 |
| 71 |     1111 | 14:20:10 |         1 |
| 72 |     1111 | 14:21:10 |    (null) |
| 75 |     1111 | 14:24:10 |         1 |
```

Comment: This does work if the data is as above but I have incorrectly stated the table data - I have amended the question to resolve this mistake

Comment: Sql fiddle always helps+1

Comment: @Justin - This is why you should never rely on autoincrement ids for anything except joins (or tiebreakers in `ORDER BY`s) - because not only **will** there be gaps, but sometimes the ordering of the id won't match the equivalent of a `insertedAt` timestamp column either...

Answer (score 0):

Edited My answer:

Well, you can use below update queries:

`UPDATE t SET t.Start/End = 1 FROM table t INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(Id) IdMin,MIN(Time) FROM table GROUP BY RecordId) t1 ON t.Id = t1.IdMin`

`UPDATE t SET t.Start/End = 1 FROM table t INNER JOIN (SELECT NAX(Id) IdMax,MAX(Time) FROM table WHERE Start/End IS NULL GROUP BY RecordId ) t1 ON t.Id = t1.IdMax`

Comment: This won't take in to account multiple RecordID's though will it? so in the above data if i ran the first query it would only put a 1 for RecordID 1111 once at ID 1 and would ignore ID 11

Comment: Edited my answer. In case of first query, it will update record where ID=1. Second query will update record where ID = Max means 13. Is it correct? Just a question - why start/end=1 where Id = 11 ? It's still under same day ?

Comment: I'd need it to add a 1 for ID 1 and ID 11 as they are 2 different instances in the table. and the 1 for ID11, even though it is the same day, it is a different instance of the record. So they haven't workd on 3 records, they have worked on 4.

Comment: what about 12 and 13 then ?

Comment: The results would need to be as in the question - 2nd table

Comment: But there should be some logic behind it? What is the criteria to select ID 1, 11 and 13 ?

Comment: it would be 1,4 and 11,13 for RecordID 1111. If you order the table by the ID then there would be a 1 for the first recordID and the last recordID before the RecordID changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work:

;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT t1.ID,
               CASE WHEN t1.RecordID <> ISNULL(t2.RecordID,0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Start/END]
            FROM TableName t1
                LEFT JOIN TableName t2
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID + 1

        UNION ALL

        select t1.ID,
                CASE WHEN t1.RecordID <> ISNULL(t2.RecordID,0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Start/END]
            FROM TableName t1
                LEFT JOIN TableName t2
                ON t1.ID = t2.ID - 1

)
UPDATE TableName
SET [Start/END] = 1
    FROM TableName t
        INNER JOIN cte
        ON t.ID = CTE.ID
    WHERE cte.[Start/END] = 1
```

Comment: This is adding a 1 to almost everything